Sublime Text 3 on MacOS: Editing Package Keybindings / Custom keybindings in packages
Problem
I'm using Sublime Text 4 on macOS, and I've installed a package that adds some useful functionality.

However, I'd like to modify the default keybindings for this package to better suit my workflow.


Specifically, I'm wondering where can I find the current keybindings for an installed package on macOS?

In some cases there will be an entry in the command palette, example:



But thats not the case for every package
I've looked through the Sublime Text documentation, but I'm not entirely sure about the correct approach for modifying package-specific keybindings on macOS.

Any guidance tailored for Mac users would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answering my own question as I found the answer while preparing the question.
The way to get to it is through:

Sublime Text (on the Mac Menu Bar) -> Settings -> Package Settings -> {wanted_package}

In this menu there should be a Settings option and a Key Bindings option.

